# C++/CLI : Interop window is not properly configured

Tags: .net, wpf, c++-cli, interop

I'm trying to load a WPF control in a C++/CLI application, using the [HwndSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndsource.aspx) class.

```
UBOOL MyWindowWrapper::Init(const HWND InParentWindowHandle) {
    Interop::HwndSourceParameters sourceParams( "WindowName" );
    sourceParams.PositionX = 0;
    sourceParams.PositionY = 0;
    sourceParams.ParentWindow = (IntPtr)InParentWindowHandle;
    sourceParams.WindowStyle = (WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD);
    sourceParams.HwndSourceHook = nullptr;

    InteropWindow = gcnew Interop::HwndSource(sourceParams);

    Control = gcnew MyWPFUserControl();
    InteropWindow->RootVisual = Control;

    InteropWindow->AddHook( gcnew Interop::HwndSourceHook(
        this, &MyWindowWrapper::MessageHookFunction ) );
    return TRUE;
}
```

And I define a Hook function so the keyboard events are passed to the window :

```
IntPtr MyWindowWrapper::MessageHookFunction( IntPtr HWnd, int Msg,
        IntPtr WParam, IntPtr LParam, bool% OutHandled ) {
    IntPtr Result = (IntPtr)0;
    OutHandled = false;

    if( Msg == WM_GETDLGCODE ) {
        OutHandled = true;

        // This tells Windows that we'll need keyboard events for this control
        Result = IntPtr( DLGC_WANTALLKEYS | DLGC_WANTCHARS | DLGC_WANTMESSAGE );
    }
    return Result;
}
```

And here are my problems :

- The window title is empty (so the "WindowName" parameter is not taken in account)
- Only some keyboard events are transferred : space, control, arrows are ok, but I can't type any character in all the text boxes

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the empty title - this is because the name of the `HwndSource` window doesn't have anything to do with the window title. The `HwndSource` window that the code creates above is a child of the window represented by `InParentWindowHandle`. It is this window whose text is used for the title bar. You should call `SetWindowText()` using that `HWND` in order to set the title of the window.

As for the typing issue, are you sure that you need to add a hook? I've only created small test apps with WPF/Win32 integration, but I don't recall having to do anything special to ensure that the WPF controls received all keyboard input.

Comment: I actually made some tests with a new empty project and it seems that the keyboard events are transmitted without the need of a hook. So it must come from elsewhere... maybe it comes from WxWidgets.

And about the title, yes, I noticed that the HwndSource is attached as a child of the Hwnd window in my test project, whereas it creates a whole new window in the main one. So it seems that attaching a HwndSource automatically creates a window, in my case, and I have no idea why.

Thanks for your reply

Comment: I think HwndSource always creates a new window - that's just how it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [known incompatibility in WPF interop within a native, modal dialogue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/cfd20c98-a809-481c-8f68-34e473c182fa/).

Summarizing:

Due to implementation details, `WM_CHAR` messages are swallowed by a modal dialog's message pump in the [`IsDialogMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645498.aspx) function before they get to your control.  You can force yourself to retrieve these by handling `WM_GETDLGCODE` in your hook function and returning `DLGC_WANTCHARS`.